# Center div inside mat-card

Tags: html, css

I want to center a div inside a mat-card but I can't figure out how.
atm the right side if my div is in the center of the mat-card, but I want to have the middle of the div to be the middle of the mat-card

This is my css atm

```
.div{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

And this is the result
[image]

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: It's already centered but you can't see it, replace `width:50%` with `display:table;` Also without any code this is a hit in the dark

Comment: That solved it!, ty